Bugzilla - Where does the application store information regarding custom fields and field items? If so how to migrate them to a new instance.?
Fairly new to the development scape. Migrated the database from one server to another but the new bugzilla instance was unable to identify and add custom fields by itself. Please help in figuring out how to make bugzilla take note of custom fields and if there is a way of migrating the custom fields info from the older instance to a newer one.
Tried running checksetup.pl but didnt help
